# How do I configure Emacs speedbar for C# mode?

Tags: c#, emacs

I'm using Emacs with [C# Mode](http://mfgames.com/linux/csharp-mode) and when I turn on the speedbar, no files show up by default.   I can choose "show all files" on the speedbar mode, but then every .cs file shows up with a '[?]' next to the name.   How do I properly configure speedbar so it shows up with .cs files by default?  How do I get the '[+]' next to each file so I can navigate inside the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ECB with CEDET is simply too bloated. I use speedbar alone with emacs and I use the original parser for C/C++. Just add this line to your .emacs and you'll be ok:

```
   (speedbar-add-supported-extension ".cs")
   (add-to-list 'speedbar-fetch-etags-parse-list
            '("\\.cs" . speedbar-parse-c-or-c++tag))
```

This handles C# perfectly without a problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I used speedbar earlier and got really irritated. I now use [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/). [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) uses its own buffer for the tree and can optionally show the outline of the CS file in a separate buffer. They all fit in the same frame while Speedbar has its own frame.

I have some [custom stuff](http://lisp.pastebin.com/m2a590520) setup for ECB. You can see it here.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.

I used

```
(speedbar-add-supported-extension ".cs")
```

and got this:

[image]