# How to make speedbar list the C functions + Unable to use sr-speedbar+macro+command history

Tags: emacs, emacs-speedbar

I am new to Emacs on Windows XP and have multiple queries which I could not find/understand after a lot of search.

1. I understand that speedbar will support showing of C functions list. As mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259364/how-do-i-configure-emacs-speedbar-for-c-sharp-mode, I added the code in .emacs as

   ```
   (speedbar 1)
      (add-to-list 'speedbar-fetch-etags-parse-list
                   '("\\.c" . speedbar-parse-c-or-c++tag))
   ```

   I see the speedbar startup but it never shows the functions. Maybe I need to install etags but cannot find it. I also found gtags but could never find a binary
2. I copied sr-speedbar.el in ~/emacs.d/ directory. I added (require 'sr-speedbar) in .emacs, commented out speedbar related code, reloaded M-x ~/.emacs but did not find any sr-speedbar. If I uncomment speedbar code and comment sr-speedbar, it shows the speedbar on loading. Emacs is able to find sr-speedbar.el in ~/emacs.d/ directory since if I change filename, it shows an error: unable to find sr-speedbar.
3. I wanted to make a keyboard macro for logging using tramp and ssh. However, when I record a macro, I have to delete multiple characters to provide the path from the beginnig i.e. emacs automatically shows the last path and so I have to delete all the characeters and then start again with ssh://. The keyboard macro records all backspaces and returns error if the backspaces are more than the length of the current path. Is there a way to avoid it
4. I configured linum package. I want it to start at the beginning of emacs session automatically with typing M-x linum. How can I do that?
5. Is there way to retrieve command history (not shell commands) and then replay some command
   Thanks again for patience on reading until the point :-)

Comment: I tried to repair some of your formatting. Please split your question into multiple. The bullet points largely have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For C, C++, and other languages, supported by CEDET/Semantic, the Speedbar is able to show functions & other objects. But you need to setup Semantic correctly, for example, you can use [my article](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) in CEDET.
2. As I understand, to enable linum-mode globally, you need to put `(global-linum-mode 1)` into your `~/.emacs`

Comment: Thank you for the response. 2 worked. However, 1 did not. Speedbar still shows the directories. I have this in my .emacs file   semantic-mode 1)
(defun my-semantic-hook ()
  (imenu-add-to-menubar "TAGS"))
(add-hook 'semantic-init-hooks 'my-semantic-hook)
(speedbar 1)
(custom-set-variables
 '(speedbar-show-unknown-files t)  The last part of custom-set-variables is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220005/how-do-i-enable-speedbar-to-display-all-types-of-files?rq=1. Also, I do see messages parsing the C files. The functions don't show up though. Please advise.Thanks

Comment: which version of CEDET do you have?

Comment: Thanks. CEDET version is 1.0. I am now reading the previous version of the article in the response. I still cannot see how to make speedbar list the functions but will read it multiple times to see if I am missing anything. Since I have WinXP with emacs, I don't think I can upgdate the package

Comment: I have been able to get Tags menu on the menu bar of emacs with proper parsing. I also downloaded ctags ctags.exe in the path in my attempt to make this work from speedbar. However, I have not been able to do that. This is how my .emacs look currently (in another comment)

Comment: require 'linum)
(semantic-mode 1)
(defun my-semantic-hook ()
  (imenu-add-to-menubar "TAGS"))
(add-hook 'semantic-init-hooks 'my-semantic-hook)
(speedbar 1)
(custom-set-variables
 '(speedbar-show-unknown-files t)
)
(global-ede-mode 1)
(autoload 'speedbar "speedbar")
(setq speedbar-fetch-etags-command "C:\ctags\ctags.exe"
      speedbar-fetch-etags-arguments '("-f" "-"))
(global-set-key  [f8] 'speedbar-get-focus)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(global-linum-mode 1) 
/10/introduction-to-ido-mode/
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
(setq ido-everywhere t)
(ido-mode 1)

Comment: for CEDET 1.0, you need to use another activation method - it described in previous version of article. You need at least specify one of `(semantic-load-...)` functions - see my old config https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-cedet-old.el.  And it's better to take at least version 1.1 - C/C++ parsing is heavily improved there

Answer (score 2):

For 3, there are two options:

- just type "/ssh:blabla" at the end of the pre-inserted directory (this directory will be ignored as witnessed by it becoming grey).
- do `C-a C-k` to erase the content of the minibuffer.

For 5, there is `repeat-complex-command` bound to `C-x ESC ESC` and there is `repeat` bound to `C-x z`.

Comment: Thanks 1. worked great. For 5. I keep on getting message that 'repeat can't intuit what you inserted before auto-fill clobbered it'. C-x z is not bound to repeat. I did M-x repeat.Also, as pmr correctly pointed out, this was a set of unrelated questions so even though you gave correct answers, I can only mark one of the posters as accepted. I apologise and can post separate queries to which you can respond. Sorry. Thanks for the help.

Comment: By default `C-x z` is bound to `repeat` at least since Emacs-20.  If it's not the case for you, it's probably due to a local configuration.